# How to add a 'Boolean' column to ms-access via SQL in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to add a `Boolean` column to a table in ms-access using SQL. I am using JET, here are the the SQL queries I have tried.

```
Query = "ALTER TABLE tabDatafiveMinutely ADD CON0001 BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE"
Query = "ALTER TABLE tabDatafiveMinutely ADD CON0001 BOOLEAN"
```

The error I am getting is 'Syntax error in field definition'

Thanks for your help

EDIT:

I would now like to make the default `null` rather than `false`. I have tried `default null` and this still gives me `false`, can anyone help with this?

RESULT:

An ms-access database can only take `true` and `false` and not null. Therefore I have decided to use and `integer` instead.

Comment: "*I would now like to make the default null rather than false.*" That is not possible.  An Access YesNo field will accept only True or False, never Null.  So you can't make it default to a value it can't hold.

Comment: I believe I have answered my edit with [this](http://allenbrowne.com/noyesno.html). Thanks Hans

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The equivalent SQL type of a `Yes/No` column is `BIT`

```sql
ALTER TABLE tabDatafiveMinutely
    ADD COLUMN CON0001 BIT   DEFAULT 0   NOT NULL
```

[Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx) says

> **Note**
>   The DEFAULT statement can be executed only through the Jet OLE DB provider and ADO. It will return an error message if used through the Access SQL View user interface.

---

As @Pere points out, Jet Engine (Access' query engine) does not apply the DEFAULT value to existing rows. You must run an UPDATE statement after altering the table.

```
UPDATE tabDatafiveMinutely SET CON0001 = 0 WHERE CON0001 IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. After spending hours on it, finally I realized that the only programatical way in PHP to set a DEFAULT for a column in an ALTER TABLE is via OLEDB using COM objects.

Comment: Oh, by the way. Be very careful with statements like the one above if executed via a SQL window in Access (haven't tried through ADO but I suspect it will act the same way): I just discovered that, for existing rows, it won't apply the DEFAULT supplied value if you set it to `true`. New ones will, though. Thanks again, MS!

Answer (score 3):

You should use the BIT datatype rather than BOOLEAN.

[Access data types.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms714540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're reading the syntax from, but you need a better source.

```
ALTER TABLE tabDatafiveMinutely
ADD COLUMN CON0001 <datatype>
```

For a Boolean type, I think you'll need to pick from BIT, INTEGER, or CHAR(1). It's application-dependent. For example, legacy systems often use 't' and 'f' in a CHAR(1) column.

Comment: The query works with `BIT` or other valid data types, it doesn't require `COLUMN`.